# How to catch exceptions using customErrors?

Tags: asp.net

In web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Errors.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error.aspx?code=404"/>     
</customErrors>
```

in page's code behind:

```
throw new HttpException(404, "404 Not Found");
```

On this line, visual studio breaks with an error:

> System.Web.HttpException was unhandled
>   by user code

Where should I catch this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Visual Studio IDE is breaking on the throw line, then you are running under debug mode.  In debug mode, exceptions cause execution to stop.

Try running the website (CTRL+F5) instead of debugging the website (F5).  However, note that you will then get the regular yellow ASP.NET exception page, as your customErrors tag specifices "RemoteOnly", which means the custom page will only be displayed to remote requests.  Your request is not remote, as you are on the machine serving the page.

To see the customErrors in action, change the tag to:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Errors.aspx"> 
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error.aspx?code=404"/>      
</customErrors>
```

and run your website using CTRL+F5.

Comment: This,is good. another question before I accept this answer: is it possible to pass the string parameter "404 Not Found" to the redirect page?

Comment: Not easily.  If that is your requirement, I would bypass customErrors and code my own exception handler in Application_Error in global.asax.

Comment: if I use Application_Error  i should disable the customErrors?

Comment: and in I should do something like:
Response.Redirect("Error.aspx?code=404&string=bla bla bla");?

Comment: Yes to both.  Disable cusomtErrors and write a redirect.  However, keep in mind that Application_Error will be called on all exceptions, not just your specific ones.  You will need to use HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() to get the exception and determine what code to execute.

Comment: Also be careful your Error.aspx page doesn't throw any errors as you could end up in an infinite loop :)